# How to upload the multiple files using fileuploader and save database usaing asp.net and sql server2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, file-upload, asp.net-4.0

i am upload the **multiple files using file uploader** or asyncfileuploader to store the file names in database sql server table column based on comma(,) and also saved in my application particular folder and another thing is file names replace to our id and extension **(example:10001A1.JPEG,10001A2.doc etc like this stored to db and folder also)**, how to write the code multiple uploade files pls give me any suggestion .

**i have the find out solution based on this url** [check this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=317)

```
but now my problem is uploading multiple files, after select the dropdown(selected event fired) field page will post back that time multiple file will be lose and another thing is first select the drop down after select the file upload , file upload is not working pls give me some suggestion
```

thank u
Hemanth

Answer (score 0):

in above question answer is first add the jquery file click the bellow link[jquey all files](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=317)

```
Step 1: Open Visual Studio 2008 > File > New > Website > Choose ‘ASP.NET 3.5 website’ from the templates > Choose your language (C# or VB) > Enter the location > Ok. In the Solution Explorer, right click your project > New Folder > rename the folder as ‘Scripts’.
Step 2: Download jQuery 1.3.2 , jQuery VS 2008 Doc and the Multiple File Upload PlugIn. Create a ‘Scripts’ folder in the Solution Explorer of your project and add these files to this folder.
Assuming you have downloaded these files, create a reference to these files in the <head> section of your page as shown below:
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery.MultiFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

Step 3: Now drag and drop an ASP.NET ‘FileUpload’ control from the toolbox to the page. Also add a Button control to the page. This Button control will trigger the upload to the server.
    <div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" class="multi" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload All"
            onclick="btnUpload_Click" />
    </div>

Observe that the FileUpload has class=”multi” set on it. This attribute is mandatory.
Step 4: The last step is to add code to upload button. Add the following code:
C#
    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get the HttpFileCollection
            HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
            for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
                if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("MyFiles") + "\\" +
                      System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
                    Response.Write("<b>File: </b>" + hpf.FileName + " <b>Size:</b> " +
                        hpf.ContentLength + " <b>Type:</b> " + hpf.ContentType + " Uploaded Successfully <br/>");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

it is working but u have post back after files uploading that file are removed so finally upload the files in any page any doubts about that [check this link](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=317)

Answer (score 0):

How about having `Dropdown` in an `Update panel` as follows

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
onselectedindexchanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Text="Hi"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Hello"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: ddl is working but image button and that click events not working how to write the asyncpostbacktrigger in imagebutton